# How do i set up the range for y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im having i bit of a hard time figuring out how to plot this graph correctly, so what im doing is:

```
    names = ['Graves', 'Fallecidos', 'Moderados', 'Asintomaticos', 'Leves']
    values = [str(df_2035_Gra), str(df_2035_fal), str(df_2035_Mod), str(df_2035_Asin), str(df_2035_leve)]
    #Values: 69, 85, 876, 3593, 27572
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))
    plt.bar(names, values)
    plt.suptitle('Pacientes x estado')
    plt.ylabel('Num. pacientes')
    plt.show()
```

And what im getting is:

[image]

So what i dont get is how to get the range on Y to be from 0 to my higher value (27572)

Answer (score 0):

Ivan :)

You can use `plt.ylim(0, 27572)`

You can check the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html?highlight=ylim#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim)

I hope it helps!

Comment: HI there, thanks for your help, i have tried that, but unfortunately does set the range within those values but it also affects the Xaxis information

Comment: I did the same code locally and it did not affect X axis. Can you post a print after implementing `plt.ylim()`? So I can understand the issue better

Answer (score 0):

The order matters. Here

```
plt.ylim(0, 27572)
plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))
plt.bar(names, values)
plt.suptitle('Pacientes x estado')
plt.ylabel('Num. pacientes')
plt.show()
```

You put `plt.ylim(0, 27572)` before creating the figure with `plt.figure`. Try this:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.bar(names, values)
plt.suptitle('Pacientes x estado')
plt.ylabel('Num. pacientes')
plt.ylim(0, 27572)
plt.yticks(np.append(np.arange(0, 25001, step = 5000), 27572))
plt.show()
```

I added `plt.yticks` to get a better range.

You can also try this:

```
figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
bar_plot = ax.bar(names, values)
plt.suptitle('Pacientes x estado')
plt.ylabel('Num. pacientes')
plt.ylim(0, 27572)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 30001, step = 5000))

for idx, rect in enumerate(bar_plot):
    height = rect.get_height() + 0.3
    x_coord = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2
    ax.text(x_coord, 1.02*height,
                values[idx],
                ha='center', va='bottom')


plt.show()
```

Would look like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S23dE.png)

Comment: Hey thats great, thanks a lot for giving me a hand!